# Filtering view by the referenced field

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a content type of `Company`, which can have multiple `Image`s. In the company node, i want to display a slideshow of the images which belong to the company.

For some reasons, instead of storing the `images` in a field of `Company`, i created another content type of `Image`, which references the `Company` through an `Entity Reference` field type.

So now i have a view of `Image`s which i want to filter using the reference field. I tried adding an `Contextual Filter`, but the filter cannot find the related images, which i think because the url is transformed. For example if the company has the name *The Company*, the path becomes */company/the-company* (i am using automatic alias).

How can i filter the images correctly in the company page? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your NID back (after it has been aliased) one of the solutions here is for you:

[Drupal 7 Contextual Filter on URL Alias](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60389/drupal-7-contextual-filter-on-url-alias)

But first I'd make sure your view is set up correctly with a contextual filter that has a relationship to the entity reference field ...

On your "view" click "Advanced". Click the "Add" button to the right of Relationships.

Find the "Entity Reference: Referenced Entity" relationship and check the box. Click "Apply". On the next screen, click "Apply" right away unless you want to change the identifier or make the relationship required.

[image]

Once you are back to your view's 'advanced options' Click the "Add" button to the right of Contextual filter and select "Content: Nid".

[image]

Under "Relationship", ensure that the entity reference relationship you added previously is selected. Next, select "Provide default value" and then set the type to "Content ID from URL". Click "Apply".

[image]

Stolen from here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004